# HiveServer Class Not Found Exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, classnotfoundexception, hiveql, java.lang.class

I'm trying to run hive from the command prompt it is working absolutely fine. But when I try running hiveserver using "hive --service hiveserver" command, I'm getting the following exception.

```
Starting Hive Thrift Server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

So I then tried with the command "hive --service hiveserver2"; still I'm not finding any solution.

Can anybody please suggest a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

May be another process (another hiveserver) already listening on port 10000.

can you check it by :
netstat -ntulp | grep ':10000' to see it and if found then kill the process.

Otherwise start the server on another port.

By the way which version you are using ?

Comment: I tried out the suggestion but there is no process or hiveserver listening to this port. And I'm using Apache Hive 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred to me when it can't find `hive-service-*.jar` in hadoop classpath. Just copy the `hive-service-*.jar` to your `hadoop lib` folder or `export classpath` in `hadoop-env.sh`. I have mentioned how to add classpath below.

Add this line in `hadoop-env.sh`:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-*.jar
```

I have mentioned the path for hive as `/usr/local/hive` since i have hive installed at that location. Change it to point to your hive installation.